# Input Pattern of specific words

Tags: html, html-input

Is there a way to make a form accept only an input pattern of either "College" or "High School" using

```
<input pattern="[College or High School]">
```

I know select is the best answer for this but I'm need to use Input Text.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the pattern attribute can accept a regexp.

Comment: Can you give spe ific example please

Comment: <input pattern="(College|High School)"> also see here https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/form-input-validation-using-only-html5-and-regex--cms-33095